# Weighted mean pandas

Tags: pandas

Im calculating weighted mean for many columns using pandas. In some cases weight can sum to zero so i use np.ma.average:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict([('ID', [1, 1, 1]),('HeightA', [1, 2, 3]), ('WeightA', [0, 0, 0]),('HeightB', [2, 4, 6]), ('WeightB', [1, 2, 4])]))

>>df
   ID  HeightA  WeightA  HeightB  WeightB
0   1        1        0        2        1
1   1        2        0        4        2
2   1        3        0        6        4


wmA = lambda x: np.ma.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, "WeightA"])
wmB = lambda x: np.ma.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, "WeightB"])
f = {'HeightA':wmA,'HeightB':wmB}
df2 = df.groupby(['ID'])['HeightA','HeightB'].agg(f)
```

This works but i have many columns of height and weights so i dont want to have to write a lambda function for each one so i try:

```
def givewm(data,weightcolumn):
    return np.ma.average(data, weights=data.loc[data.index, weightcolumn])

f = {'HeightA':givewm(df,'WeightA'),'HeightB':givewm(df,'WeightB')}
df2 = df.groupby(['ID'])['HeightA','HeightB'].agg(f)
```

Which give error: builtins.TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ.

How can i write a function which returns weighted mean with weight column name as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double nested functions, solution from [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7186#issuecomment-371255826):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict([('ID', [1, 1, 1]),
                                  ('HeightA', [1, 2, 3]), 
                                  ('WeightA', [10, 20, 30]),
                                  ('HeightB', [2, 4, 6]), 
                                  ('WeightB', [1, 2, 4])])))


print (df)
   ID  HeightA  WeightA  HeightB  WeightB
0   1        1       10        2        1
1   1        2       20        4        2
2   1        3       30        6        4


def givewm(weightcolumn):
    def f1(x):
        return np.ma.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, weightcolumn])
    return f1

f = {'HeightA':givewm('WeightA'),'HeightB':givewm('WeightB')}
df2 = df.groupby('ID').agg(f)
print (df2)
     HeightA   HeightB
ID                    
1   2.333333  4.857143
```

Verify solution:

```
wmA = lambda x: np.ma.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, "WeightA"])
wmB = lambda x: np.ma.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, "WeightB"])
f = {'HeightA':wmA,'HeightB':wmB}

df2 = df.groupby(['ID'])['HeightA','HeightB'].agg(f)
print (df2)
     HeightA   HeightB
ID                    
1   2.333333  4.857143
```